# Getting ushort format requires error in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, audio

I am a newbie in Tensorflow and I recently started to learn it. I was practicing Tensorflow on a audio data and came across this error. I was trying to play the audio in the colab notebook. Can someone help me through this?

```
pip install tensorflow-io

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

audio = tfio.audio.AudioIOTensor('/content/dataset/TrainAudioFiles/0.mp3')
print(audio)

audio_slice = audio[100:]
audio_tensor = tf.squeeze(audio_slice, axis=[])
print(audio_tensor)

from IPython.display import Audio
Audio(audio_tensor.numpy(), rate=audio.rate.numpy())
```

I am getting this error in the last cell:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-051c3ef0a0d0> in <module>()
      1 from IPython.display import Audio
      2 
----> 3 Audio(audio_tensor.numpy(), rate=audio.rate.numpy())

/usr/lib/python3.7/wave.py in _write_header(self, initlength)
    483             self._nchannels * self._framerate * self._sampwidth,
    484             self._nchannels * self._sampwidth,
--> 485             self._sampwidth * 8, b'data'))
    486         if self._form_length_pos is not None:
    487             self._data_length_pos = self._file.tell()

error: ushort format requires 0 <= number <= (0x7fff * 2 + 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is being caused, probably, because your audio data has more than one channel. In this case, the Audio class expects an input of the shape (number of channels, number of samples). But maybe your data has the shape (number of samples, number of channels). A better explanation can be found here: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html?highlight=display

To solve our problem, we can transpose our numpy array, as shown below:

```
Audio(audio_tensor.numpy().T, rate=audio.rate.numpy())
```